# Kendo grid exports headers in some languages with encoded chars

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I face some problems with export to excel in Kendo Grid. The problem is that the headers are encoded in the excel. I use Kendo UI with JQuery
The headers are fine in the grid, if the data is fine in the grid and in the exported file, but the headers in the exported file are encoded.

My Grid:

[image]

My Expxorted file:
[image]

Very Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/ulUvAZuX)

You can find some documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-export-to-excel-with-grouping)

```js
 var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          toolbar: ["excel"],
          excel: {
            fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
            proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
          },
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
            },
            schema:{
              model: {
                fields: {
                  UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                  ProductName: { type: "string" },
                  UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                  UnitsOnOrder: { type: "number" }, 
                  UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
                }
              }
            },
            pageSize: 7,
          },
          sortable: true,
          pageable: true,
          filterable: true,
          columnMenu: true,
          reorderable: true,
          resizable: true,
          columns: [
            { width: 300, locked: true, field: "ProductName", title: "Şehir"},
            { width: 300, field: "UnitPrice", title: "Statù", },
          ]
        }).getKendoGrid();

        //set the test values
        grid.one("dataBound", function(){
          this.dataSource.at(0).set("ProductName", "statù 'this is \" a test");
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <div id="grid"></div>  
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am so stupid ( : 
It looks the header was encoded but didn't think to checked that!
For ASP.NET MVC I added code to render it in raw.
Very thanks for your help!